# How to prevent Nest Js app termination on termination signals

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Is it possible to prevent application from termination in Nest Js when process is getting termination signals.

Comment: Are you referring to node killing the process on error?

If so, generally this is a bad idea but can be done by kind of hijacking the errors however its a better practice to place elements in a try catch. Otherwise you would never know where your app is erroring out.

Comment: No of course I am not trying to process the errors. In my case I am making graceful shutdown for Nest js applications. So the idea is to prevent the program form termination before all the requests is handled and response sent.

Comment: Ok.. could you use something like process._getActiveRequests() in a interval, once its 0 allow for shutdown?